# AttributeError: "NoneType" object has no attribute 'decode'

Tags: python, python-3.x, email, imap, imaplib

I am trying to read an email from my gmail inbox in Python3. So I followed this tutorial : https://www.thepythoncode.com/article/reading-emails-in-python

My code is the following :

```
 username = "*****@gmail.com"
password = "******"
# create an IMAP4 class with SSL 
imap = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL("imap.gmail.com")
# authenticate
imap.login(username, password)
status, messages = imap.select("INBOX")
# total number of emails
messages = int(messages[0])
    

for i in range(messages, 0, -1):
    # fetch the email message by ID
    res, msg = imap.fetch(str(i), "(RFC822)")
    for response in msg:
        if isinstance(response, tuple):
            # parse a bytes email into a message object
            msg = email.message_from_bytes(response[1])
            # decode the email subject
            subject = decode_header(msg["Subject"])[0][0]
            if isinstance(subject, bytes):
                # if it's a bytes, decode to str
                subject = subject.decode()
            # email sender
            from_ = msg.get("From")
            # if the email message is multipart
            if msg.is_multipart():
                # iterate over email parts
                for part in msg.walk():
                    # extract content type of email
                    content_type = part.get_content_type()
                    content_disposition = str(part.get("Content-Disposition"))

                    # get the email body
                    body = part.get_payload(decode=True).decode()
                    print(str(body))

    imap.close()
    imap.logout()
    print('DONE READING EMAIL')
```

The libraries I am using is :

```
import imaplib
import email
from email.header import decode_header
```

However, when  I execute it I get the following error message, which I don't understand because I never have an empty email in my inbox ...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-19-69bcfd2188c6>", line 38, in <module>
    body = part.get_payload(decode=True).decode()

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

Anyone has an idea what my problem could be ?

Comment: `part.get_payload(decode=True)` returns `None`.

Comment: I know but I do not undertsand why because all my emails have content in both the subject and the body

Comment: Add an if clause around it and see if it's really true.

Comment: The result with `decode=True` is already decoded; why do you attempt to `.decode()` it again?

Comment: Ok thank you this was the problem. @tripleee

Comment: The tutorial you are following had a `try:`/`except` around this single statement. Now you know why. Without a sample message, we can't really tell you why it didn't have a payload; I'm vaguely guessing some multipart container which by itself doesn't contain any payloads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/email.message.html):

> Optional decode is a flag indicating whether the payload should be
> decoded or not, according to the Content-Transfer-Encoding header.
> When True and the message is not a multipart, the payload will be
> decoded if this header’s value is quoted-printable or base64. If some
> other encoding is used, or Content-Transfer-Encoding header is
> missing, or if the payload has bogus base64 data, the payload is
> returned as-is (undecoded). If the message is a multipart and the
> decode flag is True, then None is returned. The default for decode is
> False.

(Note: this link is for python2 - for whatever reason the corresponding page for python3 doesn't seem to mention `get_payload`.)

So it sounds like either some part of some message:

- is missing the content-transfer-encoding (gives `email.message` no indication how it is meant to be decoded), or
- is using an encoding other than QP or base64 (`email.message` does not support decoding it), or
- claims to be base-64 encoded but contains a wrongly encoded string that cannot be decoded

The best thing to do is probably just to skip over it.

Replace:

```
                    body = part.get_payload(decode=True).decode()
```

with:

```
                    payload = part.get_payload(decode=True)
                    if payload is None:
                        continue
                    body = payload.decode()
```

Although I am not sure whether the `decode()` method that you are calling on the `payload` is doing anything useful beyond the decoding that `get_payload` has already done when using `decode=True`.  You should probably test this, and if you find that this call to `decode` does not do anything (i.e. if `body` and `payload` are equal), then you would probably omit this step entirely:

```
                    body = part.get_payload(decode=True)
                    if body is None:
                        continue
```

If you add some print statements regarding `from_` and `subject`, you should be able to identify the affected message(s), and then go to "show original" in gmail to compare, and see exactly what is going on.

Comment: The `email` lbrary changed significantly in Python 3.5 (I think it was); old code will continue to work, but you'll need to consult older documentation for the deprecated interfaces and methods. On the whole, the new and overhalued library is significantly more versatile and robust, whilst still maintaining some compatibility with the old version and its conventions.

Comment: @alani Can you check this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67944097/how-to-extract-the-body-of-an-email-and-save-the-attachments-using-python-imap

Answer (score 0):

High level imap lib may helps here:

```
from imap_tools import MailBox

# get emails from INBOX folder
with MailBox('imap.mail.com').login('test@mail.com', 'pwd', 'INBOX') as mailbox:
    for msg in mailbox.fetch():
        msg.uid              # str or None: '123'
        msg.subject          # str: 'some subject 你 привет'
        msg.from_            # str: 'sender@ya.ru'
        msg.to               # tuple: ('iam@goo.ru', 'friend@ya.ru', )
        msg.cc               # tuple: ('cc@mail.ru', )
        msg.bcc              # tuple: ('bcc@mail.ru', )
        msg.reply_to         # tuple: ('reply_to@mail.ru', )
        msg.date             # datetime.datetime: 1900-1-1 for unparsed, may be naive or with tzinfo
        msg.date_str         # str: original date - 'Tue, 03 Jan 2017 22:26:59 +0500'
        msg.text             # str: 'Hello 你 Привет'
        msg.html             # str: '<b>Hello 你 Привет</b>'
        msg.flags            # tuple: ('SEEN', 'FLAGGED', 'ENCRYPTED')
        msg.headers          # dict: {'Received': ('from 1.m.ru', 'from 2.m.ru'), 'AntiVirus': ('Clean',)}

        for att in msg.attachments:  # list: [Attachment]
            att.filename         # str: 'cat.jpg'
            att.content_type     # str: 'image/jpeg'
            att.payload          # bytes: b'\xff\xd8\xff\xe0\'
```

https://github.com/ikvk/imap_tools